# Use awk results as parameters to another command

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I'm extracting rows from a set of text files with awk. The files look like this:

```
1000    1    75
1000    2    76
1001    1    76
1001    2    80
```

I'm searching several directories of these with this command:

```
awk -F"\t" '$3 == "76" { print $1"\t"$2}' ../benchmark/*/labels.txt
```

awk is giving me the correct output:

```
1000    2
1001    1
```

Now for each found row I must execute a script passing these two numbers as parameters, like this:

```
./build.oct 1000    2
```

What's the correct way to do that? I don't really care about script console output (it produces files).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use `xargs` (`-l` makes it run a separate command for each line):

```
timp@helez:~/tmp$ awk -F"\t" '$3 == "76" { print $1"\t"$2}' test.txt | xargs -l ./build.oct 
$1 is  1000  and $2 is  2
$1 is  1001  and $2 is  1

timp@helez:~/tmp$ cat test.txt
1000    1   75
1000    2   76
1001    1   76
1001    2   80
timp@helez:~/tmp$ cat build.oct
echo '$1 is ' $1 ' and $2 is ' $2
```

As suggested in the comments you can also simplify the `awk` command, since both `awk` and `xargs` split on both tabs and spaces:

```
timp@helez:~/tmp$ awk '$3 == "76" {print $1,$2}' test.txt | xargs -l ./build.oct
$1 is  1000  and $2 is  2
$1 is  1001  and $2 is  1
```

Comment: You can simplify it to `print $1,$2` since xargs will split on space as well as on tab characters.

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas, correct; I was following the example of the original asker, but it can be simplified. I'll add a note to my answer about the shorter version of the `awk` command.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
awk -F"\t" '$3 == "76" { printf "./build.oct %d %d\n", $1, $2}' \
../benchmark/*/labels.txt | bash
```

Comment: Because the awk output is interpreted as shell code, you may want to sanitise your input. Replacing the %s with %d would make it safer in the event someone has managed to sneak a `;rm -rf /` in the input files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point, I edited my answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
cat ../benchmark/*/labels.txt |
while IFS=$'\t' read P1 P2 P3 ; do
  [[ $P3 == 76 ]] && echo $P1 $P2
done |
sort -u |
parallel ./build.oct
```

- you save `awk` subprocess with `readline` built-in parser (see comments below)
- you avoid dupes with `sort -u`
- you leverage resource usage with `parallel`
  (or `xargs -l1`)

Other approach of interest, piloted by `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '$3==76 && !seen[$1,$2]++ {
  print $1 FS $2 | "parallel ./build.oct"
}' ../benchmark/*/labels.txt
```

- reuse input field separator `FS` instead of literal
- dupes are discarded using an array of counters
- you learn piping to awk subprocess

Comment: For any significant volume of data awk parsing is usually more efficient than shell,  especially here where shell needs an added `cat`. `IFS='\t'` doesn't work in bash; you need `IFS=$'\t'` or quotes with an actual tab char (usually input with control-V,control-I but may vary). OP didn't express any need to remove dupes but if needed awk can do it without sorting by `&&!seen[$1,$2]++`.

Comment: I was wondering which was more efficient for massive input and my intuition is matching your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that columns 1 and 2 won't have whitespace in its entries, you can also do:

```
awk -F"\t" '$3 == "76" { print $1"\t"$2}' ../benchmark/*/labels.txt |
    while read a b; do ./build.oct $a $b; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `while` is the best answer if you have multiple outputs:

I was able to delete many created WireGuard zones with UCI
by the below command.

```bash
uci show firewall | grep wireguard | awk -F . '{printf "%s\n", $2}' | while read a ; do uci delete -q firewall."$a" ; done
```

Looping over found outputs and delete.

#### Edited

In your case all you have to do is:

```bash
awk -F"\t" '$3 == "76" { print $1"\t"$2}' ../benchmark/*/labels.txt | while read a b ; do ./build.oct "$a" "$b" ; done
```

Comment: (1) What does “if you have multiple outputs across the command line or the file” mean?   How does it relate to this question?   (2) Please don't add "thank you" as an answer.   Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.   (3) Copying somebody else’s answer and then inflating it with particulars from *your* situation, which are unique to you, isn’t really helpful — especially when you don’t *show* what data you are working with. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) And, if you *are* going to copy somebody else’s answer, you should say *clearly* that you are doing so, linking to the source and stating the name of the original author.  (5) Awk is a very powerful program; you almost never need to *combine* it with grep or sed.  In particular, ``grep wireguard | awk '{command…}'`` can be simplified to ``awk '/wireguard/ {command…}'``.  (6) Why do you say `printf "%s\n", $2` instead of `print $2`? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (7) Please learn how and when to use quotes in shell command lines.  (See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/80216)) (8) See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/80216) - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417094)

Comment: (1) simplified/edited as "multiple outputs" 
(2) (3) (4) (5) I don't know what you're talking about but I clearly mentioned that it was my command line. and using some variants won't hurt the system. 
(6) I wanted to separate my outputs with new line for another purpose, thus the use of '\n'.  
(7) Again, I don't know what you're trying to explain but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thank you for responding politely.  (1) Well, I still don’t understand what you mean by “Using ```while``` is the best answer ***if you have multiple outputs***”.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2), (3) & (4) Your first answer is essentially equivalent to [pepoluan’s answer](/a/137934/80216) but adapted to your problem.  Your second answer is ***identical*** to their answer except for spacing.  (2) Posting somebody else’s answer as a new answer looks like you’re saying “Hey! This answer works! Thanks!”  (4) [Copying other people’s work without giving credit to the original author](/help/referencing "How to reference material written by others") is [forbidden here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/271976 "What to do when plagiarism is discovered").  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) What do you not understand?  Look at the difference between your first answer (``grep wireguard | awk '{…}'``) and your second answer (``awk '$3 == "76" {…}'``).  (6) My point was that, while `printf` prints only the characters you give it, `print` automatically prints them on a separate line.  Not only is it shorter, but there is a technical reason why `print x` is preferable to `printf "%s\n" x`.  (7) See my edit to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu awk has a `system` function. You could run something along the lines of

```
awk '$3 == "76" { system("./build.oct " $1 " " $2) }' ....
```

Comment: (1) As [Stéphane Chazelas hinted in his comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137761/use-awk-results-as-parameters-to-another-command#comment220119_137767), this can be dangerous if an attacker can write to your input file and say, for example, “``;shutdown now 76``” or “`;rm  *  76`”. (2) This almost certainly runs a new bash process for each line of input.  (I don’t see any other answer that does that.)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', Thank you! (1) true. That is why I wrote "along the lines of". I never know how to deal with it: The correct solution is tends to hide the basic idea.. (2) true. It can be a problem if you have millions of lines but in many cases this is what we really need, and what is going to be the reasonable solution.